# How to configure oAuth2 when Authorization Server is also the Resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to setup a very basic oAuth2 authentication in spring boot 2.x.x using either **authorization code grant** or **implicit grant** but I can't seem to access the Resource server (which resides in the same spring boot app as the Authorization server) after the token is obtained.

Following is the configuration of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] IGNORE_URIS = {
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/resources/**",
            "/h2-console/**",
            "/common/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/error"
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(IGNORE_URIS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/product/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN").and()
                .httpBasic().and().formLogin().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCrypt() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("my-client-id")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                .authorities("ADMIN")
                .scopes("all")
                .resourceIds("product_api")
                .secret("{noop}secret").redirectUris("https://google.com").accessTokenValiditySeconds(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

So far so good. I am able to reach the default Spring login page by typing the following Url in the browser.

http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my-client-id&redirect_uri=https://google.com

Then The login page shows up and I enter my credentials.

[image: basic auth login]

After I log in I can then grant access to **"my-client-id"** app.

[image: approve]

Eventually after I approve the app I can see the newly generated access token in the URL bar of the browser which is something like this.

`https://www.google.com/#access_token=f2153498-6a26-42c6-93f0-80825ef03b16&token_type=bearer&scope=all`

My question is that All of this flow won't work when I also configure a Resource Server.

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("product_api");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? When I try to access the `oauth/authorize` url as before I get the following:

[image: error]

Why? How can one access the login page and retrieve the token? What Am I missing?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but in `WebSecurityConfiguration` why are there two beans of type `PasswordEncoder` defined, both with the same implementation? As far as I understand deleting one function would not change the outcome.

Comment: Not even an hour after writing this comment I strumbled upon the "autowiring by name" mechanism of spring, which explains how a different function name of a `Bean` provider results in different execution. Damn, this is some invisible magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
@Order
```

Annotation to specify order for WebMvc and ResourceServer classes

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

and for Resource Server

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

If you want to see workable example, you can check it here https://github.com/alex-petrov81/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/auth-server-also-resource 
I've created it from your code example.

Comment: Those Spring magic annotations solved my problem again. Thank you for the working example!

Comment: At first thanks a lot for the example! I am currently implementing something similar. I followed your workable example, and I am able to get the tokens, but when I want to use the tokens to access my resources I get an 401 unauthorised response. Do you have an idea why this could happen? For me it seems that the WebSecurityConfiguration catches all requests and do not let anything being handled by the ResourceServerConfiguration and therefore I am getting the 401

Comment: @grahan I am having same problem have you solved it?