# Spring Boot 2 Oauth how to implement Implicit Code Flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

Currently I am in the process of introducing OAuth to my Spring application, but I have not luck to integrate it correctly.  I am using **Spring Boot 2**.

My requirements are:

- Authorization and resource server are the **same application** running on the same server
- **Implicit, Authorisation Code Grant and Resource owner credentials grant** flows need to be supported
- The API I want to secure lives under "/api/v1/"

None of the flows is working correctly.. What I achieved so far is based on the tutorial by https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-oauth2-role-based-authorization and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386009/4454752

So my **AuthorizationServer** looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("as466gf");
    return converter;
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
      .inMemory()
      .withClient("my-client-id")
      .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token", "password")
      .authorities("ADMIN")
      .scopes("all")
      .resourceIds("product_api")
      .secret("$2a$10$jfAHmk4szDU/t1qLGlFTLukuBZL0ZHZGUJQICePjjyq6IrLOS934.")
      .redirectUris("https://example.com")
      .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200)
      .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(7200);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer
      .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
      .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {

    endpoints
      .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
      .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
  }

}
```

Then the **ResourceServer**

```
   @Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId("product_api");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .requestMatchers()
      .antMatchers("/**")
      .and().authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
  }


}
```

And last the **WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Resource(name = "userDetailService")
  private UserDetailService userDetailsService;

  @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/**")
      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER").and()
      .httpBasic().and().formLogin().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(encoder());
  }
}
```

My UserDetails and the complete user management is already set up, so no need to change something here.

Now to the use cases.

If access "/oauth/token":

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  --header 'authorization: Basic bXktY2xpZW50Om15LXNlY3JldA==' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'grant_type=password&username=admin&password=test'
```

So with the my-client:my-secret I get an response with access token and refresh token. But if I want to use the access token on my API I get `Access denied`. If I check the token with `/oauth/check_token` it says that the token is valid.

Same problem if I use "/oauth/authorize" (Implicit Flow). I know that I need the login page from spring, to make it work, that's why I added `formLogin()` in `WebSecurityConfig`. But If I query `http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my-client&redirect_uri=https://example.com` I get redirected to `/login` I log in,then get the access token from the redirect url, but again if I use this token I get the `401` error.

The endpoint I want to access is handled by the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserController {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);
  public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";



  private final AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;
  private final UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade,
    UserService userService) {
    this.authenticationFacade = authenticationFacade;
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Optional<User> getCurrentUser() {
    LOGGER.info("Requesting /api/v1/user/me");
    return userService.findByUsername((String) authenticationFacade.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that something with the Security configuration is messed up, but I have no idea what it could be. I looked trough a lot of guides online, but I did not find a single one which explained all the authorization code combined. I think it might be a small bug with authenticating the URLs but I have no clue what it could be.

I would be very happy if someone knows an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Move your configure() implementation from WebSecurityConfig to Resource Server configure() method as below

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/**")
      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
```

Rest of the configurations in configure() method are not required